# Want to create full width nav bar, but I can't because of my border

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a nav bar. But rather than the border going across the whole width of the website it stays within the paremeters set by the border. I can't seem to be able to create the navbar and continue with the vertical border throughout the rest of the website. I've attached the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x5v2sks6/) as a visual guide as I may not be explaining it appropriately. Much obliged in advance for your help.

```
HTML - 
<section class="section section--full section--intro">
 <div class="contain">
  <h1>
   <span class="identity"> TestTest</span>
   <span class="menu">MENU</span>
  </h1>
 </div>
</section>

CSS -
.section--full {
min-height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
.section--intro {
background-image:url();
background-attachment:fixed;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
line-height: 1.5;
display: table;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
padding: 20% 0px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-family: GalaxiePolarisLight;
}
.section--intro .identity {
display:block;
top: 0px;
letter-spacing: -0.5px;
font-size: 35px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color:#fff;
margin: 0;
padding:20px 30px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 99;
position: fixed;
float: left;
}
.section--intro .menu {
display:block;
top: 0px;
color: #fff;
letter-spacing: -0.5px;
font-size: 40px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 0;
padding:20px 30px;
z-index: 99;
right: 0px;
position: fixed;
float: right;
}
html {
background-color: rgb(189, 189, 189);
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's not necessary to reset margin on `html`, it does not have any by default.
2. You do need to reset the margin on the `body` tag, also make it `min-height: 100%;` likely you want it in your case.
3. If you want to exclude any borders from box model, use [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 2):

Just reset the bodys margin [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x5v2sks6/1/)

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh /*Set the body height*/
}
```